# Why does my code Not connect to my Hub or Node?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

Why does my code Not connect to my Hub or Node?

1. I need to execute my test cases using a node.
2. I have successuflly setup a hub and node.
3. My code:

   ```
       case "chrome":
           if (null == webdriver) {
               System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
               webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
               DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
               webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capability);
   ```
4. Output from the hub: 
   [image]
5. Output from the node:
   [image]
6. testng output:
   [image]
7. Hub & Node Setup: JSON File: 
   [image]

Comment: Please check the chrome driver path once again.

Answer (score 0):

On node registration you should add chrome driver path like this

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<pathToChormeDriverExe>/chromedriver.exe
```

In your case, something like this should work:

```
 java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Temp/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe 
-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar 
-role node 
-hub http://172.16.1.48:4444/grid/register 
-browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=5, platform=WINDOWS"
```